# X/y coordinates of new node in directed graph are not changing in the tick event

Tags: d3.js

I want to create functionality to a *add a new node* to an exsiting d3 directed graph.

I managed to add the node with the link but for some reason, after the simulation completes the first time and I try to drag the new node around it's being detached from the rest of the nodes.

I looked at the DOM and I see that when moving the old nodes, their x/y coords are chaining but the x/y of the new node are not chaining.

Only when trying to move the new node, its coords are changing.

I see that the new nodes and link are part of the existing nodes and links but I'm not sure why it happens.

Also, I can't seem to add a node without rendering the entire graph and I'm not sure if it's possilbe.

I'm using d3 version 5.